# Maintaining zooming state of a live updating plotly chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

**Question :**

How to maintain plotly trend char zoom state when the chart gets updated each time. I have sample example to reproduce the issue below.

**Example :**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)


generate_data <- function() {
  data.frame(
    timestamp = seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.time() - 3600), Sys.time(), by = "min"),
    value = runif(61, min = 100, max = 200) 
  )
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  plotlyOutput("trend_chart")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  plot_ui_state <- reactiveValues(zoom = list())
  
  # Random data generation and plot update
  output$trend_chart <- renderPlotly({
    invalidateLater(10000, session) # Update every 10 seconds
    data <- generate_data()
    
    p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~timestamp, y = ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
      layout(title = "Random Data Over Time")
    

  })

  

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```